# Critical edition on 3 columns

Tags: parcolumns, critical

Is it possible to typeset a critical edition with a three columns section?

I need to have numbered lines and footnotes (like `edtext`) on all three columns.
Text length is different on the columns and I need then justified.
I tried using minipage, but it is more like a mess and manual breaking on pages.

Here is MWE with note issues (regular edition notes
`edtext` are not printed and the ones with `\footnotemark` are printed either on the first or the last page of the environment regardless of their position in text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\parcolumns[distance=3em,sloppy]{3}
\colchunk{%
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum{1}
{[}1.47{]} \textbf{B}: Aliud exemplum ponunt subtilius. Videmus quod
vas, licet non potest de \edtext{quolibet}{\lemma{quolibet2}\Afootnote{some note text}} liquore plus recipere nisi unum
cyphatum una vice, potest tamen \textless post\textgreater{} cyphatum
aquae, abiecta aqua, recipere de meliori liquore alium cyphatum, ut puta
vini, et abiecto, adhuc\footnotemark{} alium
cyphatum de meliori liquore in infinitum, 
\pend
\endnumbering
}
\footnotetext{some text}

\colchunk{%
\beginnumbering
\pstart
{[}1.47{]} \textbf{P}: Aliud exemplum ponunt subtilius. Videmus quod
vas, licet \textless non\textgreater{} potest de quolibet liquore plus
recipere nisi unum cyphatum una vice, potest cyphatum aquae recipere et,
abiecta aqua, recipere de meliori liquore, ut puta de vino, alium
cyphatum, et abiecto illo, adhuc alium, et sic in infinitum, cum ultra
quemlibet\footnotemark{} liquorem
potest Deus causare meliorem. 
\pend
\endnumbering
}

\colchunk{%
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum{1}
\pend
\endnumbering
}
\colplacechunks


\footnotetext{the other note}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum{2}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the footnote descriptions to be placed at the bottom of a page? The section with three columns is relatively easy to create even in the middle of a document. You have at least two packages you could make use e.g. [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) or [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

Comment: If possible to be placed at the bottom of the page it will be great if not... I have already tried 'parcolumns' but is not perfect.

Comment: The footnotes slightly complicate things. I think you should provide [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) because you are giving too few details and provided recommendations will very likely be missed. The MWE can show what you have so far and things which are not as you expected.

Comment: I have added an example. It is working somehow (printing numbered text, and also able to print footnotes however the position is either on the first or last page of the column section regardless of the `\footnotetext` position.